# Why does [[no_unique_address]] interfere with base classes in MSVC?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++20

The following program [returns 1 on all compilers except MSVC, where it returns 2](https://godbolt.org/z/vEj5jG6aM):

```
struct E1 { };
struct E2 { };
struct
#ifdef _MSC_VER
    __declspec(empty_bases)  // This doesn't make any difference
#endif
    S : E1
{
    char c;
    [[no_unique_address]]
#ifdef _MSC_VER
    [[msvc::no_unique_address]]
#endif
    E2 e;
};

int main() { return sizeof(S); }
```

Why is this? Shouldn't `no_unique_address` cause `e` and `c` to overlap?

Comment: `no_unique_address` _permits_ them to overlap, but the actual decision is up to the compiler/ABI. MSVC already decided to not act on the standard `[[no_unique_address]]` for backwards-compatibility and use `[[msvc::no_unique_address]]` instead. They seem to be much more conservative, maybe there is another compatibility issue that prevented them from applying the optimization in this case.